# Apache mod_rewrite rules not being processed from .htaccess files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Can anyone help to solve problem with overriding in apache2?

I have enabled mod_rewrite in apache2.

But apache is just ignoring my .htaccess file's rewrite rules.

This is my virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.modomain.eu
    ServerAlias mydomain.eu *.mydomain.eu mydomain.es *.mydomain.es
    DocumentRoot /home/sites/mydomain.es

    <Directory /home/sites/mydomain.es>
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 5):

.htaccess files aren't processed if you have AllowOverride set to "none". If you set it to "allowoverride all" it should allow you to override the settings in your vhost configuration file.

Answer (score 2):

Read [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.1/mod/mod_rewrite.html) e.g.:

> By default, mod_rewrite configuration settings from the main server context are not inherited by virtual hosts. To make the main server settings apply to virtual hosts, you must place the following directives in each  section:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

Comment: You don't need `RewriteEngine On` in the main config. This can be done directly in .htaccess.

In the above example, the `AllowOverride` is set to `none`. Unless this is turned on, you will be unable to process the .htaccess file.

Comment: @shreddd ok; and thereafter you could need what I wrote (which is into the docs, if you missed the detail)

Comment: Dude.. you're awesome.. *tears*.. :P

Answer (score 0):

Set the following:

```
AllowOverride All
```

In the `<Directory>` stanza

This will allow the .htaccess file to be able to override various settings (such as rewrite rules)